# The Fourier sine transform of $f(x)/\sin x$

Tags: integration, reference-request, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

Is the following result
$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{\sin x} \sin(\lambda x) \, dx = f(0) + 2\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k\pi),$$
where $\lambda$ is an odd integer, correct? If so, is it well known? It looks like the Fourier sine transform of $f(x)/\sin x$.

Comment: Are there some assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I think $f$ is continuous, positive, and decreasing on $[0, \infty)$. I found this formula in an old book. It resembles the Poisson summation formula.